# Configuration cache out of sync

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, timer-service

I've been investigating a recurring issue on a SharePoint 2013 Server Farm.
In fact, we have to clear the configuration cache at least twice a week, which is not normal.
It has been cleared yesterday, yet when I compare the config.ini value on each server, I find that one of them keep being out of sync. The value is a few digits lower than the other servers.

Any idea why this behavior occur ?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate A/V exclusions in place? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-you-use-file-level-antivirus-software-in-sharepoint-01cbc532-a24e-4bba-8d67-0b1ed733a3d9

Comment: Hi, yes, just checked with the team.